# History substitution fails when implemented in shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, history-expansion

The below command works in command line

```
rsync -avh -r /Source/09_03_2016/ /Destination/
echo $(basename !:3)
```

> Output 09_03_2016

But when I do this in shell script it does not work

```
#! /bin/bash

/usr/bin/rsync -avh -r /Source/09_03_2016 /Destination/;
echo $(basename !:3)
```

> Output  !:3

Comment: Are u sure u are using bash shell? type command ps $$ tell output..

Comment: Output :PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
  6169 pts/0    Ss     0:00 -bash

Comment: Why did you add a `;` at the end of the `rsync` command line in the script?

Comment: @Kusalananda removed and tested still the same output

Comment: What is the meaning of "!:3" in echo command ?

Comment: @GC13 It's a history expansion construct, which is meant for interactive use and not really useful in a script.

Comment: Just write `/Source/09_03_2016`! History expansion is meant for typing things quickly. It has no business obfuscating a script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following directives in your script:

```
set -o history
set -o histexpand
```

This will enable the history expansion which is only enabled for interactive shells by default.

See `man bash` section `HISTORY EXPANSION` and `SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS` command `set` for details.